# DNAT - cascaded switch

Tags: switch

I am trying to allow a service through my firewall to BOX1 that cascades off my managed switch.

NET<------ [Firewall WAN_Firewall LAN] ------> [Managed Switch]------> [Unmanaged Switch]--------> BOX1

I know it's not an issue with my DNAT or my filter.  This used to work when BOX1 was connected directly to the Managed Switch.  In my firewall log I see the traffic come through from the outside source IP to my WAN int.  But firing up wireshark on BOX1 doesn't show anything.  I wasn't sure if there is anything on the Managed Switch I could enable to get this to work? Netgear GS108T.  Or if I will have to bite the bullet and pull in a new line.

Thanks

Comment: what's the firewall hardware/software? Home network?

Comment: Sophos UTM installed on a custom box.  Home network.

Comment: ...i see we now have an answer too. So we'll migrate.

Comment: Have you ruled out the possibility that the unmanaged switch isn't working?

Comment: It works when box1 is connected to it, that is internet access.  Can ping other boxes connected to that switch.  Tonight I plan to re-connect box1 to the managed switch using an ethernet power line adapter.  That will help me rule out the issue.

Comment: On box1 can you see incoming pings from the FW ? Can you ping the FW inside interface ? Can you browse to the FW/UTM management web page from box1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing lots of details here, what port? whats is box1 ip address? By dnat do you mean you have 2 nat's?

Go to your firewall and make sure the service you want is forwarded to a static IP. Say it's a webserver so forward port 80 to port 80 on "insert IP Here".

Now if you have a NAT on the switch, you shouldn't unless your using it to do DHCP and hand out IP's in a different subnet. Everything should work.

Make sure your computer has the static IP forwarded earlier, in the case of double nat, make sure that ip is the switch ip and configure it just like the firewall.

Comment: 3389, 172.16.2.6.  No its a destination NAT.  So WAN -> Service 3389.  Change dst to 172.16.2.6 3389.  NAT is not enabled on the switch and is not handing out DHCP addresses.  The firewall handles all this.  Like I said though this worked fine when the box was connected to the managed switch which just hangs off the firewall.  I'm just not sure why this would not work unless the unmanaged switch is doing something strange with it.

Comment: Oh I see you added a un-managed switch and it's now longer working. Well you could look at the arp table in the manage switch and the computer. You could try to ping the managed switch from the computer or the computer from the wirewall. Does the computer 172.16.2.6 have internet? Lot's of basic things need to be done before trouble shooting more advanced topics. trying switching out the cable's between the managed switch and the computer, or at least testing them.

Comment: Yep the newly added device was the unmanaged switch.  So before box1 connected to the managed switch and it worked.  That box was moved into a different room with only one drop so I plugged in an unmanaged switch so I could hook up the other boxes in that room as well.  Everything works except for the dnat.  At this point I'm wondering if I will just need to drop in a new line.

Comment: Dropping in a new line wont work, if the other computers are working and talking the switch and the cables are fine. It's a problem with the configuration on the router or the client, double check everything, did the ip of the computer change or it is static?

Comment: Its a static IP

Comment: So it turns out I'm a walking idiot.  It was the damn firewall on the damn pc.  Nothing network related.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Your welcome, it happens to all of us.